# Separating chars java

Tags: java

Can't get a print out on this. Anyone know what the deal is?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SeparatingCharacters {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println(" Please enter name");
        String text = reader.nextLine();
        int length = text.length(); 
        for (int i = 0; length == i; i++) {
        System.out.println(i + ". character: " + text.charAt(i));

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: for(int i=0; length > i; i++)

Comment: Did you run this in your IDE debugger and step through it one line at a time?  That is the place to start.  If you don't know how to use the debugger, make that (learning the debugger) your highest priority.  It is a fundamental requirement of writing software.

Comment: Thanks Ken, wasn't sure why == was working but a > works too. I was close heh

Answer (score 2):

Check your for loop. `i=0` and `length == i` ?

Edit : It should be

```
for(int i=0; i < length; i++)
```

Comment: I thought Check your for loop was sufficient. Sorry my bad. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should check your loop again, your put the condition wrong. Fix your `length == i` into `i < length` then it should be fine.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println(" Please enter name");
    String text = reader.nextLine();
    int length = text.length(); 
    for (int i = 0; i <  length; i++) {
    System.out.println(i + ". character: " + text.charAt(i));

    /* ---edit---
    make the print number start from 1
    System.out.println((i + 1) + ". character: " + text.charAt(i));
    */

    }
}
```

Test output :

```
 Please enter name
Mike Tyson
0. character: M
1. character: i
2. character: k
3. character: e
4. character:  
5. character: T
6. character: y
7. character: s
8. character: o
9. character: n
```

Comment: Any way to make it start at 1.? adjusting termination cuts off the the first letter..(edit, just add one to the sout)

Comment: yup, just add 1 on sout, I already edit the code, you can see that on the code comment..